# Is there a way to select n characters that are before the a certain character

Tags: string, oracle

I have a string, which represent a file.
The file extensions have not the same size.
The 2 last characters before the '.'  give an important information.
Is there a way (probably with regex) to change this 2 characters?

```
Mystring := blabla || two_characters_to_change || '.' || file_extension

Mystring_concrete_example := 'blabla93.pdf'

select regexp_replace('Mystring_concrete_example','??','39') 

expected result:= 'blaba39.pdf'
```

does somebody know what should I write instead of '??', in oder to select the 2 characters before the '.' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have extensions that doesn't contain dots (like `.tar.gz`), then you may search for the dot at the end and extract two previous characters with regex groups:

> ```
> with a as (
>   select 'blabla93.pdf' as file_
>   from dual
> )
> select
>   file_
>   , regexp_replace(
>       file_
>       , '(.*)(.{2})(\.[^.]+$)'
>       , '\1' || 'something' || '\3'
>   ) as file_new
> from a
> ```
>
> ```
> FILE_        | FILE_NEW           
> :----------- | :------------------
> blabla93.pdf | blablasomething.pdf
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=1da8787a2693dfa730b996b973f0de65)*

Explanation:

- `(.*)` - 1st capturing group, should contain any number `*` of any characters `.`.
- `(.{2})` - 2nd capturing group, should contain exactly two `{2}` any `.` characters
- `(\.[^.]+$)` - 3rd capturing group, should begin with dot `\.` followed by any positive `+` number of any characters, except dot `[^.]` and placed at the very end of the string `$`
- Replacement `\N` stands for `N`'th capturing group.

You may also use this online regex tester that contain explanations: https://regex101.com/.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `INSTR` to find the point and then use `SUBSTRING` to get the parts that we want to keep.

```
create table paths(path varchar(100));
insert into paths select 'blabla93.pdf' from dual;
```

```
with findings as
(select 
  path,
  INSTR( path, '.') pos
from paths)
select 
  substr(path,1,pos-3) || '22' || substr(path,pos) as newPath
from findings
```

> ```
> | NEWPATH      |
> | :----------- |
> | blabla22.pdf |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1d00f7a7fc61e1a151fa848775ad022a)*

Comment: Don't use `substr(path, pos, 100)` as that will cut off the substring after 100 characters. Use `substr(path, pos)` without a third argument to get the entire remaining sub-string.

Comment: @MT0 - modified (I was working with varchar(100) but you don't know who will use the code and get unexpected errors. **Thank you**